# Update two entities sharing the primary key with a Symfony2 form

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I have two entities: `User` and `CompanyInfo`.

The relationship between both is `oneToOne`, the `User` can have zero or one `CompanyInfo`, and one `CompanyInfo` belongs to one `User`.

Therefore I setup them to have the same primary key (User's id):

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="CompanyInfo", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
 * @var CompanyInfo
 */
protected $companyInfo;
...
}

class CompanyInfo
{

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="companyInfo", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @var User
 */
protected $user;
....
 }
```

I'm having an issue trying to expose the them at the same time so that they can be updated by submitting only one form:

In the UserFormType I have the following line:

```
    $builder->add('companyInfo', new CompanyInfoFormType(), ['required' => false, 'by_reference' => false])
```

The `CompanyInfoFormType` has the following:

```
    /**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => '....\Entity\CompanyInfo',
        'intention'  => 'registration'
    ));
}
```

It all works fine, the form is rendered with both the user and the company info fields. When creating a new user & companyInfo it works but only because I did the following in the `onSuccess` of the `UserFormHandler` (Basically persist the `User` in first place, looks a bit hackie but couldn't find a nicer way):

```
    if ($user->getCompanyInfo() instanceof CompanyInfo) {
        $companyInfo = $user->getCompanyInfo()->setUser($user);
        $user->setCompanyInfo(null);
        $this->entityManager->beginTransaction();
        $this->entityManager->persist($user);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
        $this->entityManager->persist($companyInfo);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
        $this->entityManager->commit();
        $this->entityManager->refresh($user);
    }
```

Now, the issue is when I'm trying to update a user that already has a companyInfo. For some weird reason, doctrine is thinking that the `CompanyInfo` entity doesn't exist and it's trying to do an INSERT rather than an UPDATE. It's like if the entity `CompanyInfo` it's not managed by Doctrine and therefore when doing the cascade persist, tries to create a new one.

Comment: Why your are removing company `$user->setCompanyInfo(null)` from user entity i guess thats the reason doctrine is creating new one

Comment: Just add a userId to the company and vice versa.  Give up the attempt to keep the primary keys in sync.  It will only cause problems downstream.

Comment: Khalid that bit of code is executed only on the POST, that doesn't run on the PUT or PATCH, so it must be something else. I'm setting it to null because otherwise the cascade-persist doesnt work as both entities have same PK

Comment: Cerad I don't understand what you said sorry. I'm not trying to keep the ids in sync, I'm just trying to use the user_id as FK and PK of company info. I could use an auto incremental for the company info but I think it would be a waste as I don't really need a specific company info id at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to find a solution for this, it's not ideal though, but it works. Basically, the `process` method of my `UpdateFormHandler` looks like follows:

```
/**
 * @param UserInterface $user
 * @return bool
 */
public function process(UserInterface $user)
{
    $this->form->setData($user);

    $method = $this->request->getMethod();
    if (in_array($method, ['PUT', 'PATCH'])) {
        $this->form->submit($this->request, 'PATCH' !== $method);

        if ($this->form->isValid()) {
            /** @var User $user */
            $this->saveCompanyInfo($user);
            $this->onSuccess($user);
            $this->userManager->reloadUser($user);
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Create link companyInfo -> User when persisting CompanyInfo for first time
 *
 * @param User $user
 */
protected function saveCompanyInfo(User $user)
{
    if ($user->getCompanyInfo() instanceof CompanyInfo && !$user->getCompanyInfo()->getUser()) {

        $user->getCompanyInfo()->setUser($user);

    } elseif ($user->getCompanyInfo() instanceof CompanyInfo) {
        /**
         * If companyInfo exists and has been modified, doctrine things that it's a new entity
         * detached from the manager, and will try to insert a new row on the company_info table (which crashes, as the PK (user_id) already exists).
         * By calling ->merge, we obtain an attached/managed instance,
         * so that it will be properly cascade persisted when the user is saved.
         */
        /** @var CompanyInfo $companyInfo */
        $companyInfo = $this->getEntityManager()->merge($user->getCompanyInfo());
        $user->setCompanyInfo($companyInfo);
    }
}
```

I'm sure (I hope) there are better ways, but I'm looking forward to hear them, as this is the only thing that worked for me.

I hope it helps.

Regards,
Javier